# What does "by a pretty wide margin" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I guess it means China is likely to bring us quite a lot of profit over time. Is that correct?

> “China is very likely to be our largest international market likely **by a pretty wide margin** over time.” Chief Executive Officer Kim Lopdrup said in an interview last week.

Source: [Trade War or Not, U.S. Companies Follow the Consumer to China](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-08-28/trade-war-or-not-u-s-companies-follow-the-consumer-to-china?srnd=premium-asia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your confusion. "Margin" has several meanings, and one is related to finance (the "profit margin"). But that's not the one used here.

In this case, "margin" is used in the sense of "numerical difference":

> China [will] be our largest international market... by a **large difference**.

That is, the difference in the amount of trade with China, and with the second-biggest market, will be large.

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that among the numerous countries of the world, China will be the first in terms of US product sales. "By a pretty wide margin" indicates that the second-largest market for US products will fall far behind China in terms of sales volume.